# Can linprog give an integer value of x's?

Tags: matlab, integer, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I have a linprog code that has x1,x2,x3 and x4 in the objective function.

The results I get give me values in the form:

```
 x = 
6.6667
0.0420
0 
0
```

Which in the case I am trying to model doesn't make physical sense because the x's represent the number of units of a specific technology, and therefore for example 0.0420 doesn't in fact exist. Is there anyway to "force" linprog to find the optimum integer value of x?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's called [integer programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) and in general is NP-hard.  It's not covered by `linprog` as it's a completely different and much harder problem.

[Here's a related question (but not a duplicate) from Stack Overflow about Integer Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970686/integer-linear-programming-example-and-good-tools?rq=1).

Comment: that would be using the bintprog solver? On a high level, how does the  binary format move to higher integers in Matlab? e.g from say for example results like 1 0 0 1 to 5 0 0 2?

Comment: `bintprog` is only for cases where the unknown variable can be only 0 or 1.  You might be able to reformulate your problem into a binary integer programming problem, but this is just a hunch.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using mixed-integer programming (you would get one when adding "integer constraints" like "x integer" to the linear program in linprog).

Straight forward I would recommend using [Scip](http://scip.zib.de/) as it is "free" or [Gams](http://www.gams.com/) which is a commercial product but offers a free trial version for smaller instances.

A more detailed post on mixed integer programming and the correspondign solvers can be found at [scicomp][3]

[3]: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2679/objects-in-buckets-assignment-optimization-problem "scicomp".