# Solve linear programming equations with integer result

Tags: matlab

I am using the following matlab tool to solve my linear equations
x = linprog(f,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)
all things going well with me, but the result of x vector not integer values. so how can I set the x vector to be integer value or take value 0 or 1 only.(I mean solve linear equations for integer result).

let me explain more:
if I want to min x for the objective function   8X1 + X2
subject to
x1+2x2≥−14, −4x1−x2≤−33, 2x1+x2≤20
the result of X1,X2 not integer value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Matlab version 2014a above, then there is [intlinprog](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html) for what you are looking for.

UPDATE:
Since you have Matlab 2012b, so i strongly suggest you to use this [perfect tool](http://www.google.com) at first, but you need something called Internet connection [j/k :-)]. By the way, there are some solutions:

1. [something](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25259-linear-mixed-integer-program-solver) on Matlab exchange.
2. [GLPK](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) (GNU Linear Programming Kit)
3. [answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970686/integer-linear-programming-example-and-good-tools) on stackoverflow

Comment: for sorry I am using matlab 2012b, Do you know any way to do that on matlab 2012b?